# SQL: Store IN time and OUT time in two columns or just 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For an easy and faster Time and Attendance calculation, which way should I go for storing IN and OUT time data?

1. Store IN and OUT time per employee in a single row

[image]

2. Store single value (with inout bit value, 0 = IN, 1 = OUT)

[image]

Comment: What engine do you use ? Do you use MySql ?

Comment: You may want another column to indicate source: Employees don't always clock so you may want an administrator to make a manual entry or some other mechanism to track bad/erroneous entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st Proposed solution is good but if you want to go for the second solution you will need an another column to identify the related `Time In` and `Time Out` records for an employee.

Something like....

```
EmployeeID INT,  RecordID INT, TimeClock DATETIME,          INOUT BIT

   101               1          2014-01-01 09:00:05.123       1
   101               1          2014-01-01 17:10:05.123       0
   201               2          2014-01-01 09:00:05.123       1
   201               2          2014-01-01 17:10:05.123       0
```

But with your 1st approach you will need to insert records and then Update each record when employee leaves, I would rather go for your second option but with my suggested additional column.

Comment: How can I manage when an employee punches two times by mistake. That way I will only have one TimeClock entry without the other IN or OUT record.

Comment: What happens when an employee doesnt punch the card at all? these are the scenarios of garbage data, and its very simple garbage in garbage out. You cannot expect correct results after putting in wrong data. This is something you need to handle on application layer. If two entries are made by the same employee within few seconds reject one and only use the last one, some this sort of logic.

Comment: Thanks, how can I assing that RecordID because the time records are not consecutive by employee. Does it really make sense of RecordID?

Answer (score 0):

Its good to go with two columns for the two fields for easy calculation